# wpa_supplicant: high CPU usage

Tags: drivers, network-manager, cpu

My Ubuntu 18.04 system freezes almost once a week. I observed that the reason to this problem is that sometimes suddenly wpa_supplicant uses the 100% of CPU in one core. When this happens after a while the whole system freezes and I cannot restart with a safe way (only power off).

Some system information:

```
Laptop Dell Vostro
RAM: 8 GiB
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8 
Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)
```

Network information

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep net -A2
Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:08a7]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `wpa_supplicant`?

Comment: @Jos you 're right thank you ! It was a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's wpa_supplicant itself. You probably have an issue with your CPU getting too hot if it runs too long at the 4.6Ghz Turboboost speed. You could check on the temperature development during a stress test and see if it freezes because of that.

You then might want to try changing to the powersave CPU governor if not already or limit the maximum Turbo boost speed to something less than 4.6 Ghz. Check out man cpupower, you could for instance try out "cpupower frequency-set --max 3 Ghz" and see if that runs reliably during a stress test.

You could also try cleaning the vents and see if that causes the temperature buildup.